# numpy buggy slice stop when overriding getitem of ndarray

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to override getitem of a numpy `ndarray` like this

```py
import numpy as np
class myarr(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, ij):
        return ij   # just return the slice object itself
```

In case of an open end, however, I retrieve a strange number for the slice stop and a negative slice start is increased by one:

```
>>> a = myarr([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> a[-3:]
slice(-2, 9223372036854775807, None)
```

Here I would expect `slice(-3, None, None)`, which is also the outcome of

```
>>> np.s_[-3:]
```

So why is this behaviour and how can it be fixed?

It does occur Python 2.7.14 + numpy 1.14.0, not with Python 3.6.9 + numpy 1.18.5.

Comment: [9223372036854775807 is the largest signed integer you can represent in 64 bits](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10571632), so it is the last element you will every be able to address in NumPy, so it basically is "the end".

Comment: If it does not cause any problems, it doesn't need to be fixed.